# Using onblur jquery function to check validation data after submit POST?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I use `$("#User_Username").on("blur", function ()` to check valid user for `UserNameTextBox` in my Vie. And another field in my form, i use the default validation of ASP MVC to valid, such as Textbox, DropdownList.

The jquery validation works fine. My main problem is when user click on `Register` button (they dont care whether or not the value on `UsernameTextbox` valid, just click) , if another filed is not valid, it return the form and show error message.

At this case,, my valid status on `UsernameTextbox` lost, i have to click to this textbox to event `onblur` fire again.
Any suggestion? I have tried to disable `Register` button until `UserNameTextBox` valid, but it is more solution for my validation.

Comment: do you use a asp.net button to submit your form?

Comment: When you click on the submit button also, you have to call the same set of methods/functions u r calling on blur 
Ex:considering you have id='submit' for submit button $("#submit").on("click", function (){ //do your stuff here });

Comment: I use `<input id="createuser" type="submit" value="Đăng ký tài khoản" />` to submit my form. The problem if user click button to submit form with another filed is not valid, it return this form and show validation message, and the USername text need me to focus on to valid agian.

Comment: @SAM It's the `<input/>` element, is there event onclick?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<input id="createuser" type="submit" value="Đăng ký tài khoản" onclick="return myValidationFunction();" />
```

Return false if validation fails!

The return false should stop the default submit behaviour

Comment: Did you mean :`function SubmitForm() {
    $("#createuser").on("click", function () {
        CheckUserNameExits();
    });
}` .